# Select subfield returns empty string when looped by wc_get_related_products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

On my single product page, I am trying to get the related products using woocommerce's built in `wc_get_related_products()` function, which returns an array of product IDs.

So I loop through the related product IDs and runs a `get_field( 'workshop_details', $product_id )` inside it. The `workshop_details` field is a group field, which has the following subfields: `workshop_type` (select field), `workshop_date` (date field), and `workshop_row` (text field).

Problem is, the return value of `workshop_type` subfield is always an empty string, but the other subfields are returning fine. I tried to change the return value of the select field to value, label, and both, but nothing changes.

Another problem is, when I loop through all the products by just using `get_posts()`, and running the `get_field( 'workshop_details', $product_id )`, it returns the `workshop_type` properly.

But I can't just use `get_posts()` instead of `wc_get_related_products()` because it would ignore the upsells/custom related products on the product.

Comment: [DOC](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/)

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question now, apparently it was a data problem. ‍♀️